# When connecting to ttserver,I always get the "TimeoutException"?

Tags: timeout, timeoutexception

The title of the exception is "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out(5000) waiting for operation"!
How can I set a approprate time for not exceeding the time out limit?!
The whole exeption stack is:

```
**java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation
    at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.getMulti0(XMemcachedClient.java:1155)
    at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:1026)
    at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:1064)
    at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:1051)
    ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of reason can cause the ttserver client throw TimeoutException.
In my situation, it was because of the replication to a node which did not exist.So when delete the startup parameters mhost and mport,the problem was fixed.....

Hope this can help someone else....